# csv to xml conversion using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm not a developer, but I work in the tech industry and have basic knowledge of xslt.
I would really appreciate help with the scenario below. Perhaps once I have an example I could extrapolate to other use cases.

In csv, i have columns:
Name
Location
Job 1
Job 2
Job 3

Job 1 has other attributes such as start time, end time & pay
Job 2 has shift, bonus
Job 3 has sales, ops

example values in csv:

```
Name, Location,Job_Type,Start_time, End_time,Pay, Shift, Bonus,Sales, Ops
john, london,Job_1,800,1900,400, , , , ,
john, london,Job_2, , , ,evening,20000, , , 
john, london,Job_3, , , , , , 200,500
```

How do I make sure that these 3 separate rows in csv can be converted into one xml structure:

```
<name>john</name>
  <location>london</location>
    <Job_1>
      <Start_time>800</Start_time>
      <End_time>1900</End_time>
      <Pay>400</Pay>
    </Job_1>
    <Job_2>
      <Shift>evening</Shift>
      <Bonus>20000</Bonus>
    </Job_2>
    <Job_3>
      <Sales>200</Sales>
      <Ops>500</Ops>
    </Job_3>
```

I was thinking of setting up a variable which is name and location first.
Then do a for each maybe. Not sure how I would create a statement if name is this.name for each element though.

I would really appreciate help with this.

Comment: Look [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unparsed-text) for how to handle text in XSLT-2.0+.

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 3 (as supported by the open-source Saxon 9.8 and later HE software and by Altova 2017 and later) you can break up the input string with the CSV into a sequence of string arrays and then group them on the first array item as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs array"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="csv-input" as="xs:string">Name, Location,Job_Type,Start_time, End_time,Pay, Shift, Bonus,Sales, Ops
john, london,Job_1,800,1900,400, , , , ,
john, london,Job_2, , , ,evening,20000, , , 
john, london,Job_3, , , , , , 200,500</xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="lines" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($csv-input, '\r?\n')"/>

  <xsl:param name="headers" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(head($lines), '\s*,\s*')"/>

  <xsl:param name="data" as="array(xs:string)*" select="tail($lines)!array{ tokenize(., '\s*,\s*') }"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template" expand-text="yes">
      <root>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="$data" group-by=".(1)">
              <record>
                  <xsl:for-each select="subsequence($headers, 1, 2)">
                      <xsl:element name="{.}">{head(current-group())(position())}</xsl:element>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                      <xsl:element name="{.(3)}">
                          <xsl:variable name="values" select="."/>
                          <xsl:for-each select="(4 to count($headers))">
                              <xsl:if test="normalize-space($values(position() + 3))">
                                <xsl:element name="{$headers[current()]}">{$values(position() + 3)}</xsl:element>
                              </xsl:if>
                          </xsl:for-each>
                      </xsl:element>
                  </xsl:for-each>
              </record>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38Zn/2

For self-containedness of the example the CSV data there is passed in as a string parameter but you could of course use `<xsl:param name="csv-input" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text('file.csv')"/>` instead to load the data from an CSV file.

Of course XSLT 3 is not really necessary, with XSLT 2 the usual way is to convert the CSV into XML and then group that as needed.